# How can I fix the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError caused from ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, out-of-memory

in my app there is a big RecyclerView with many ImageViews in it, inside every ImageView is a drawable (200x200, 12kb).
In the RecyclerView are around 50 ImageViews.

If I click on one ImageView the image changes to a pressed version and a sound is played, just like a soundboard with many different images as buttons.

My problem is following crash report I get in the Developer Console:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream (BitmapFactory.java:856)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream (BitmapFactory.java:675)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream (Drawable.java:2228)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:4211)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:4085)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:2005)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1987)
  at android.content.Context.getDrawable (Context.java:464)
  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable (ContextCompat.java:463)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:102)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource (AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource (AppCompatImageView.java:94)
  at com.tresgames.terscope.Tab3Adapter$1.onClick (Tab3Adapter.java:102)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5697)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22526)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This line is bold:

```
at com.tresgames.terscope.Tab3Adapter$1.onClick (Tab3Adapter.java:102)
```

Here is the class with the onClick method:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SoundboardViewHolder holder3, final int position) {
        final SoundObject object = soundObjects.get(position);

        final Integer soundID = object.getItemID();

(SoundObject)object
        holder3.itemTextView.setText(object.getItemName());
        holder3.itemImageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
        holder3.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final Context context = v.getContext();
                holder3.itemImageView.setImageResource(pressedResource[position]);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        holder3.itemImageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
                    }
                }, 500);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                EventHandlerClass.startMediaPlayer(v, soundID);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        holder3.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

 choose between several actions
                EventHandlerClass.popupManager(v, object);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I heard about solving the OutOfMemory error with recycling the Bitmap, but I'm pretty new to Java so I don't know how to solve the problem in my case.
Everything on this app works perfect instead of this, I hope someone can help me.

If you need more Information or Code I will send it immediately.

Thanks

Comment: OOM error? I thought RecyclerViews were made to _avoid_ this.

Comment: you can try using Glide library to load the images as a thumbnail at 0.1 resolution instead. They also do caching which may help if you got duplicated images.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" inside Manifest.(However its not good idea to solve this problem)

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to use glide
and Add

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

like this image

[image]